# Linear Regression and High Dimensional Categorical Data

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, categorical-encoding, many-categories

I've read that mean encoding is useful for classification tasks with high dimensional categorical data.

My question:

What kinds of encodings are effective for high dimensional categorical data in linear regression tasks? For example, can mean encoding be adapted?

Some possible applications:

- Assigning credit limit using job title (we need to encode job title)
- Predicting wait time at a nightclub from shoe type (we need to encode shoe type)

Comment: See  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146907/principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-levels

Answer (score 1):

Mean encoding seems to be popular in machine learning, but you should try better ways. The problem that dummy coding (or "one-hot") with many levels uses much memory, can be solved with sparse matrices. But still there might be too many parameters with one for each level, so some kind of *collapsing of levels* could be useful, see [Principled way of collapsing categorical variables with many levels?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146907/principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-levels).

What you should do might also depend on which kind of model you are using (you didn't tell us). For one idea see [Strange encoding for categorical features](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398903/strange-encoding-for-categorical-features/414892#414892).